# Neo4J: 3-Level Expand node with filter

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

For a new POC I have the following use case:

For a given node do a 3-Level expand but apply also a filter on all expanded node (means I want to filter all resulting nodes for certain properties)

Test set:

- nodes: ~ 17 Mio
- edges: ~ 40 Mio
- Properties: ~ 2650 Mio

My first solution looks like this:

```
MATCH path=(startNode:Entity {id:'RVDJRcV_yfXbG0-syGKp3Q..'})-[*..3]-(endNode:Entity) 
WITH path 
WHERE ALL (n IN nodes(path)[1..] 
WHERE n.key = '1' AND n.domain = 'facebook.com' AND n.investigationID='any') 
RETURN path 
LIMIT 100
```

This does the job, but it is not very fast. Avg. query times in my test set are 2-3 seconds but with many timeouts (time > 30 seconds). I assume the problem is the path handling and that my node has lots of properties...

Explain plan:
[image: Explain plan]

Variant 1: i removed the "with path"
[image: Variant 1]

Solution:
Based on the tip that i should avoid [1..] in the query

```
MATCH path=(startNode:Entity {id:'v-jXIO7kozAa35gMUpUkvg..'})-[*..3]-(endNode:Entity) 
WHERE ALL (n IN nodes(path)
WHERE n=startNode OR (n.key = '1' AND n.domain = 'facebook.com' AND n.investigationID='any')) 
RETURN path 
LIMIT 100
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Can give the cypher `explain` of the query ?

Comment: The `with` between the MATCH and the WHERE creates a logical segmentation between the match and filter, so the Cypher planner can't optimize the MATCH, so you will need to remove that line before the WHERE can be optimized.

Comment: Please repost the EXPLAIN after testing that change.

Comment: if i remove the "With PATH" it is only a little better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can filter during expansion with variable-length paths, Cypher currently can't apply that filter during expansion when you're working with a slice of the list instead of the whole list. It will fall back to doing the full var-length expansion, and then applying the filter to all results found.

We need to only use `ALL (n IN nodes(path) ...`, we can't use the slice of the path.

To do this, we need to add one more predicate within the all() function. Since the start node probably doesn't meet the current predicate, we'll create an exception for it:

```
MATCH path=(startNode:Entity {id:'RVDJRcV_yfXbG0-syGKp3Q..'})-[*..3]-(endNode:Entity) 
WHERE ALL (n IN nodes(path)[1..] 
 WHERE n=startNode OR (n.key = '1' AND n.domain = 'facebook.com' AND n.investigationID='any')) 
RETURN path 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Wait, are you saying you should or shouldn't use `[1..]`? (because it's still in the cypher example). Instead of the head exception, will using `ALL(n IN tail(nodes(path)) WHERE ...` work? Or will the plan see that as still slicing the path up?

Comment: Actually, let's try something else first, I may have overlooked something small but important. In the query in your description, try removing `WITH path` from the query, you may see a drastic change.